# Why I get access writing violation when using memset with a big _Size?

Tags: c++, memory, memset

So I have a variable in my C++ code of type `_Scalar` who can takes a lot of different types (int, double...).

So I initialize my pointer with the **new** operator in my template class. When I want to allocate memory, I use the memset function in the constructor of my template class.

```
//At the beginning of the class
_Scalar* m_data;

//In the constructor
m_data = new _Scalar;
memset(m_data, 0, sizeof(_Scalar) * m_size)
```

For a `m_size` of 15 for example, everything is ok. But when `m_size` is 10000, I get an access writing violation error. I watched the `m_data` variable in Visual Studio and this is what I get:

[image]

So what's the problem and how to solve it? I'm pretty new to C++.

Comment: Well probably because you write to protected memory.

Comment: When you only allocate one but try to initialize 10000, of course it won't work.

Comment: `new _Scalar` only allocates a single _Scalar instance, you want `new _Scalar[m_size]`, you're running off memory and getting lucky with m_size = 15.

Comment: `std::vector<_Scalar> m_data` is probably a better choice.

Comment: @Evg a true statement

Comment: It's for school so I can't use vector ;)

Comment: P.S. don't use `memset` in C++ unless you *know* that the variable is a POD type.

Comment: I think my teacher wants us to use memset but it's for matrix purpose so only numbers

Comment: What is `_Scalar`? If it is declared by user code then you should be aware that it is forbidden to declare identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Such identifiers are *reserved* to the compiler/standard library implementation. Violating this rule causes the program to have undefined behavior.

Comment: I thought it was a generic type for multiple types in C++. Like by defining a scalar in a template class, you can use this class with int or double variables. In the code the teacher gives us, _Scalar is used in template classes and sometimes with the ```typename``` keyword. For example:

```template<typename _Scalar, int _Size> class xyz```

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe Yes using a template parameter like this for when you want to use your class/function for different types is exactly what they are for. `_Scalar` is just a name that you can change then, though. It has no special meaning in the language. However, the language specification forbids identifiers to start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter. Neither you or your teacher should use such identifiers. `Scalar` would be fine, but `_Scalar` is not.

Comment: Using these reserved identifiers causes undefined behavior and although it may work out most of the time in practice, it can fail horribly if you happen to use a reserved identifier that the compiler uses for something else.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you really want this:

```
m_data = new _Scalar[m_size];
for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
   m_data[i] = {};
}
```

Or as others have pointed out, just this will suffice:

```
m_data = new _Scalar[m_size]();
```

Depending on what's inside a Scalar object, the memset may or may not be safe.  I've seen some bad fails with memset being used to "zero out" an object that contained members with allocated memory.

A better approach might be to have Scalar's constructor just insure all members are zero'd out.  Depends on if you have control of that class's code.

Comment: Why not just default initialize it: `m_data = new _Scalar[m_size]();`

Comment: Oh yeah it works too haha. I don't know what my teacher wants

Comment: `memset` does exactly what it says and writes _an exact bit pattern_ to a range of memory.  The problem comes when your objects don't match your expectations for what their bit pattern should be.

Comment: @ÉmilePettersen-Coulombe There is almost never a point to using `memset` in C++ (but there is in C). In C++ you can initialize memory correctly directly as shown above or use `std::fill` which does the same as `memset` for trivial types but is type-safe and also behaves correctly for non-trivial types.